# What`s the better way to send the data made by php to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

For example, I have some data from a database that could be fetched by php.

And I would like to show the data as a chart by some fancy javascript chart plugin.

There are two ways to do the job.

First, let php output the row data in the JS script.Such as the following code,

**chart.php**

```
<?php
   $data=Array(); 
   //$data would be assigned some value from database
?>
<script>
   var data=[];
   data=<?php echo json_encode[$data];?>;
   draw_fancy_chart(data);
</script>
```

The pros are that this method is quite efficient.The user would just directly see the chart once the page is requested from the server(supposed the draw_fancy_chart function is highly efficiency).

But the cons are that I cannot extract the JS scripts and even do some minify on a draw_fancy_chart.js.And all the user could view my JS by the view-source.

Second method were using AJAX.

**chart_ajax.php**

```
echo json_encode[$data];
```

**chart.html**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "chart_ajax.php"      
  }).done(function(data) {
    draw_fancy_chart(data);
   });
</script>
```

The pros are that I can pack all the JS script into a JS file.
But the user experience is bad, the user would face a loading spinner due to an ajax request. And as we know, the request is not needed.

Could someone give me a better solution? Many thanks.

Comment: Side note: Doing `var data = [];` followed by `data = ...` creates and throws away an array. Just `var data = ...` is sufficient, or `var data; data = ...` if you prefer declarations separated from initialization.

Comment: `And all the user could view my JS by the view-source.`, I don't see how doing an ajax request protect you from users seing your JS source? If the user wants to see your source, he will be able to see it.

Comment: The first one is better IMO - for the second one you would need to write more code, e.g. when the ajax call is failing, you have to write a new server side controller for that request, etc.

Comment: Thanks Holt. I mean at least I can pack the JS script and do some minify. As I know, embedding php in JS script were hard to maintain and less secure. Buth T.J provide an good solution.

Answer (score 3):

A third option that maintains separation while keeping the number of HTTP requests to a minimum:

```
<script>
var data = <?php json_encode($data)?>;
</script>
<script src="your-javascript.js"></script>
```

...and then `your-javascript.js` uses `data`. The downside here being that `data` is a global variable, so choose a likely-to-be-unique name for it to avoid conflicts (the global namespace is *ridiculously* crowded).

Answer (score 0):

The second method is better.  I don't think the user experience is bad.  Numerous sites use the same technique.  You have control over how the UI looks (eg. "Loading chart data..." etc) and the total load time should be almost the same as the first solution.

Another advantage is that (if you want) you can continuously update the chart without having to reload the whole page.

Comment: Agree for large amount of data, because you could put something like `loading...` instead of having a HTML page taking 10 seconds to load, so the user experience is improved. But in case of small amounts of data, I think it's unnecessary overload, and user side, it is not really good to have a page with missing elements without any information.

Comment: I was assuming it was a reasonable amount of data since it was coming from a database.  But even if it is for a small amount of data, the HTTP request time is going to be minimal. It will be like loading an image.  It wouldn't be a problem unless it was a *really* busy site.

Comment: When I say "a small amount of data", I mean something like a single variable, not even an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can minify inline javascript.

If  you want everything to be loaded in one request you could do it like this:

```
<script>
    //Minified js for draw_fancy_chart

    var data=<?php echo json_encode($data);?>;
    draw_fancy_chart(data);
</script>
```

If there is a lot of data, you should consider making an ajax request so that the rest of the page is visible while loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>

var data = <?php echo json_encode($data)?>;

</script>
```

the json need php echo and you will get javascript object contain you data

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider serving your `draw_fancy_chart` javascript code into a separate js file as T.J. Crowder pointed out. This is applicable in both scenarios and it is best practice as it will allow you to minify your javascript code and the browser will be able to cache it for further requests.

About the data, the second method has some advantages regarding user experience.

The page will load very fast (except the chart) and then the user will only have to wait for the chart to load. This is better than waiting for the whole page to load, including the chart. The total time until the chart is finished is almost the same in both cases, the network bandwidth required to transfer the data is probably the bottleneck.

You will be able to refresh the chart without reloading the whole page, using another AJAX request and the same code.

Keep in mind that a page will probably require many requests to load javascript files, CSS, images, etc. One more request to load the data will not make the difference